# Detect HTTP Proxy error for WebRequest

Tags: c#, proxy, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse, system.net.webexception

How to detect that a WebRequest failed due to a web proxy error and not a target web server error?

```
try
{
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.example.com");
    request.Proxy = new WebProxy("localhost");
    var response = request.GetResponse();

    return response.GetResponseStream();
}
catch(WebException webex)
{
    //Detect proxy failure
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is difficult. Here are some suggestions:

- The `webex.Response.ResponseUri` property contains the URI of your proxy server instead of the server you were trying to contact.
- The `webex.Response.StatusCode` property is one that *always* refers to a proxy problem, e.g. `ProxyAuthenticationRequired`. Unfortunately most statuses could refer to either a proxy error or a server error.
- The `webex.Response.Headers` collection contains non-standard entries that you recognise as being generated by your proxy server. For example, the Squid proxy returns the header `"X-Squid-Error"`, with its own proprietary set of statuses.
- The `webex.Response.ResponseStream` stream contains an HTML or plain text error message in a format that you recognise as being generated by your proxy server. You might test to see if it contains the URI of your proxy server.

In your catch block, make sure that you log full details of the `WebException` object, including all the properties mentioned above. You can then analyse the log data and develop an accurate test for proxy errors.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could catch InvalidOperationException and then check the message for "proxy".

The message would say:

The proxy name could not be resolved: 'localhost'

Comment: Yes, checking for specific keywords, like "proxy" or actual proxy address in the exception message would be a choice, but I was looking for something "more deterministic"

Comment: Yeah its not the nicest approach, however they throw an InvalidOperationException, and therefore dont provide you with very much!